# my linux can't see atrix 4g's second sd card device

Tags: android

My device is a Motorola Atrix 4G (ME860). It has an 11G internal SD card, and I inserted a new 16G SD card into the SD Card slot.

When I connect the phone to my computer with a USB cable, it shows two removable disks on my computer system, on Windows.

But on Linux (my Gentoo box), it shows only one device (`/dev/sdc` - the internal 11G SD card). I can't see the other 16G SD card device.

How can I mount the external SD card on Linux?

`dmesg` info:

```
<7>[ 1136.355862] hub 1-1:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0002
<7>[ 1136.356126] hub 1-1:1.0: port 1, status 0101, change 0001, 12 Mb/s
<7>[ 1136.459809] hub 1-1:1.0: debounce: port 1: total 100ms stable 100ms status 0x101
<6>[ 1136.532634] usb 1-1.1: new high speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
<7>[ 1136.625519] usb 1-1.1: default language 0x0409
<7>[ 1136.634493] usb 1-1.1: adding 1-1.1:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
<7>[ 1136.636506] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: usb_probe_interface
<7>[ 1136.636527] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
<6>[ 1136.636661] scsi13 : usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
<7>[ 1136.636788] usb 1-1.1: adding 1-1.1:1.1 (config #1, interface 1)
<5>[ 1137.642196] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
<3>[ 1140.358324] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
<3>[ 1140.358333] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
<3>[ 1140.363312] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
<3>[ 1140.363321] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
<6>[ 1140.367887]  sdc:
```

Comment: What does `dmesg(1)` report when plugging it in?

Comment: I add dmesg output, any useful info ?

Comment: I already fix this problem. I didn't set CONFIG_SCSI_MULTI_LUN in .config when compiling kernel.

Comment: @PengLiang Please post this as an answer and accept it, so that when someone else has this problem, they'd find your solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to fix this problem: I hadn't set the `CONFIG_SCSI_MULTI_LUN` option in my `.config` when configuring my kernel.